# Select 4x4 grid with one line of code

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select columns A to D and rows 1 to 4 (but the range will be dynamic), cell D4 being empty, using one line of code. Unfortunately neither of the following seems to work:

```
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Select
```

nor

```
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
```

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: What defines the end of the data? If D4 in the example below is blank then it isn't the last populated cell

Comment: Why does the code have to be on one line?

Comment: Hey Chris. This is all the code in this macro. Basically I am trying to mimic excel behavior when doing ctrl+shift+right and then ctrl+shift+down, it works fine this way. The code doesn't have to be on one line, but if I split it in two it doesn't work as desired also.

Comment: If cell D4 is empty then staring in A1 and pressing ctrl+shift+right then ctrl+shift+down wont select up to D4 as the cell is empty.

Comment: Also if you can replicate it then record the code as you do it and check out the code to see what that gives you.

Comment: Sure, but the macro recorder code is based on selection, and if I replace the selection reference in it with specific cell reference, it doesn't do what I want it to do anymore.

Comment: If you record the code and press ctrl+shift+down it should record it as .End(xlDown) and not a cell reference.

Comment: Can you specify what is dynamic. Can the number of columns increase? Can the number of rows increase? Can the base cell (`A1`) move? All three?

Answer (score 3):

This code take the last cell of a current region from A1 (`CTRL+*`)

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
```

Should work.

And

```
Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
```

should give the adress of a last cell in the worksheet.

Comment: Even if the last cell is empty?

Comment: Yes but I edit my post I don't answer With that, in fact Just Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select should work

Comment: Thanks Bla2, it works, but do you know how to adjust the code so it will work even when the selection would be somewhere in the middle of the sheet and also with an unempty column directly next to it? CurrentRegion will not be enough in such case.

Comment: I think 
something like Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address

Should Give the last Cell adress (Like Current Region but with the Worksheet)

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how knowing the last cell's address helps me. Anyway, as the column next to the selection is longer than the selection I want to make, I think this method is not applicable here. Sorry for being such a PITA.

Comment: that's ok but like said @robinCTS We need more information( like some data Exemples or other explanation)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the 4x4 block starting at `A1`, use:

```
Range("A1").Resize(4, 4).Select
```

If you want to select the block containing all the values in the 4 columns staring at `A1`, use:

```
Range("A1:D" & Range("A1:D" & Cells.Rows.Count) _
  .Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row).Select
```

To move the base cell to, for example, `E7` instead of `A1`, simply replace `A1` and `A1:D` above with `E7` and `E7:H` respectively.